# Adding react native debug configuration to IntelliJ

Tags: react-native, debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am new in React Native and I am going to add react native debug configuration to IntelliJ IDE. The problem is I cannot see react native in the list of debug configurations. How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.
[image]